# jsPdf not working in Visualforce page for large documents

Tags: visualforce, community, jquery, pdf, html2canvas

**Task:** To convert a document[visualforce generated one] into pdf.

**Solution I am using now :** making use of salesforce `renderAs="pdf"` method

**Problem Faced :** RenderAs pdf method is not working as expected in all cases.
                So we have opted for alternate method.

**Alternate Solution I am trying now :** Canvas & Jspdf

**Steps I have done**

1. html2canvas to convert the document into image.
2. jsPdf method to convert the image into pdf.

**My code**

```
   <script>
     $(function() {

     $("#finalPdf").click(function() {
     html2canvas($("#widget"), {
     onrendered: function(canvas) {
     var img =canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg,1.0");  
    //           console.dir(canvas);
      var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');


      pdf.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 15, 15);

      pdf.output('datauri');

    }
  });
})
});

</script>
```

Here the `jsPdf` method is working for small sized document alone. For documents with more content its not responding. Do anyone know about this??

Comment: When you say "RenderAs pdf method is not working as expected in all cases". Can you add more details on when its not working?

Comment: we are facing alignment issues with it. In certain cases the alignment is collapsing when we run the pdf in batch. So we thought of taking a picture[ screenshot] of the generated document and then to convert it into pdf, So that the alignment won't collapse anywhere.

Comment: Just a thought, but i think Jspdf expects valid html5 while visualforce doesn't create that. That may be part of your problem.

Comment: But I am not giving the html part to jsPdf, I am converting the visualforce page into jpeg image and then giving that jpeg to jsPdf. Will it still cause problem?

Comment: Sorry, you're right! To be honest, i'd be careful with building your solution unless it is a very simple page that you are after. You are now trying to combine visualforce, with all it's uniqueness with htmltocanvas which has its own oddities and jsPdf which may or may not be-able to handle everything htmltocanvas does. It could work really well, or it could turn into an incomprehensible mess.

Comment: Btw, in the Salesforce stack exchange we are probably better at debugging the visualforce rendered as pdf, than the javascript solution your trying to build right now. If you want to you can try posting your visualforce code (or the part that makes your alignment collapse) and see if someone knows what to do?

Comment: @Kasper, Actually we are looking for a permanent solution, thats why I am tring "JsPdf". We can't change the css styles everytime in business.

Comment: Why would you have to change the css every time? If done correctly than the visualforce and the css are written in such a way that no matter your input data, the pdf will render correctly. I'm guessing that will be a necessity however you decide to render your pdf. Have you looked at the new pilot feature in summer 17 called advanced pdf? https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_vf_advanced_pdf.htm